# Extracting Sitecore Analytic Data

Tags: sitecore

I'm new to Sitecore concepts, and I'm searching almost five days for an answer. I couldn't find what I'm looking for.

I'm trying to access Sitecore analytic data from a web service. I found a web service of Sitecore with using this [document](https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/65/sitecore_web_service_sc65_a4.pdf). I want to extract data that are about [this](http://habitat.demo.sitecore.net/api/Demo/ExperienceDataContent?_=1521448400102). I believe this is a [public demo site](http://habitat.demo.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Feature/Demo).

I want to access Web Api, then extract data and use it at my own project. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

When working with Sitecore 9, the API you want to use to connect to analytics data is known as xConnect. A secure connection is required using trusted certificates, so you cannot connect to an existing instance that somebody else setup like the Habitat demo you linked to.

xConnect is an abstraction API that allows you to collect and search all data in the xDB. The architecture fully supports both vertical and horizontal scaling of xConnect services separate from your Sitecore installations.

**Resources**

You can read more about xConnect here in the official developer documentation: https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/xp/xconnect/

There is an xConnect tutorial available here: https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/xp/getting-started/#tutorials-xconnect

I also have a small tutorial you can use on GitHub to start learning the concepts: https://github.com/jst-cyr/XConnectTutorial